# Chrome extra padding on select

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'm having issue with select on chrome desktop.I can't seem to remove the extra padding on chrome:

[image: Output]

My HTML :

```
<select class="demo">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

My CSS:

```
.demo { 
    border: solid black 1px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
        width: 100%; 
    }
```

I can't seem to get rid of the extra padding on the left hand side.

Could someone please help with a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Try to put it on `option`?

Comment: Tried, doesn't affect the visible part